# Laplace equation inequalities and essential supremum

Tags: inequality, partial-differential-equations

I started a PDE course and got some issues with technical problems. This one centers around the proof for the solution of the laplacian equation. I am asked to verify the following inequality which one also finds on page 24 of L.C. Evans 'Partial Differential Equations'.

$$ \Bigg\lvert \int\limits_{B(0,\epsilon)} \Phi(y)\Delta_x\,f(x-y)\, dy \Bigg\rvert \leq C\Vert D^2 f\Vert_{L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)}\int\limits_{B(0,\epsilon)}\lvert\Phi(y)\rvert \, dy \leq \begin{cases} C\epsilon^2 \lvert \log \epsilon \rvert & (n=2) \\ C\epsilon^2 & (n\geq3)\end{cases}$$

**What I already did**: I already estimated the RHS integral part for the case $n = 2$. This was quite easy since I can switch to polar coordinates after which it is more or less ordinary integration and results in $\frac{1}{2}\epsilon^2\log\lvert\epsilon\rvert$ as upper estimate from the integral part alone.

**Where my problems are**: I have two problems. First, I don't have a clue what the essential supremum norm on $D^2f$, that is the Hessian matrix, is. I know what the essential supremum norm means and could compute it for ordinary functions but how do I apply it to matrices? I searched online and in the appendix of Evan's book but nothing came of it. Second, how can I estimate the RHS integral for $n\geq 3$? I can no longer switch to polar coordinates, how do I integrate this not so easy function

$$ \Phi(x) := \frac{1}{n(n-2)\alpha(n)}\frac{1}{\lvert x\rvert^{n-2}}$$ function over an $n$-dimensional ball or produce a plausible estimate of it? Evans himself writes those inequalities down without any comment.

Comment: For the second problem, there is more than one way to see it. Can you prove that $\Phi(x)$ is integrable over the unit ball? Are you familiar with the formula $\int_\Omega |f(x)| dx = \int_0^\infty |\{ x \in \Omega : |f(x)| > t \}| dt$?

Comment: Well, I am not familiar with your formula but I think I can write $B(0,\epsilon) = (0,\epsilon) \times \partial B(0,\epsilon)$, at least I did it that way now. At the end it perfectly matches the upper bound with some additional multiplicative constant $C$. But now you really got me thinking. For $n = 3$, the function $\frac{1}{x}$ isn't even Lebesgue integrable over $(0, \epsilon)$. How would that change in a multidimensional setting?

Comment: It's either this formula or the following version of Fubini: $\int_{B(0,r)} f(x) dx = \int_0^r s^{n-1} \int_{S(0,1)} f(sy) dy ds$. You can find these in (almost) any book on real analysis.

Comment: Yes, exactly this I used. There is still the question about what $\Vert D^2 f \Vert_{L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)}$ means though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**First problem.** The estimate for the integral is simply 
$$ \Bigg\lvert \int\limits_{B(0,\varepsilon)} \Phi(y)\Delta_x\,f(x-y)\, dy \Bigg\rvert \leq C\Vert \Delta_x\,f(x-y) \Vert_{L^\infty({B(0,\varepsilon))}}\int\limits_{B(0,\varepsilon)}\lvert\Phi(y)\rvert \, dy $$
followed by a pointwise estimate $|\Delta f| \le C |D^2 f|$, where $|\cdot|$ stands for any chosen matrix norm. Let us choose the $l^1$ norm $|A| := \sum_{i,j} |a_{ij}|$, then this inequality is trivially satisfied with $C=1$, as $|\Delta f| \le |f_{x_1 x_1}|+\ldots+|f_{x_n x_n}|$. Of course in general $C$ depends on the choice of the matrix norm.

The $L^p$ spaces (including $p=\infty$) of matrix-valued functions $A$ are defined in just the same way as the $L^p$ spaces of real-valued functions $g$ - we just put $|A|$ in the place of $|g|$.

**Second problem.** According to the spherical Fubini theorem, 
\begin{align*}
\int_{B(0,\varepsilon)} \frac{dx}{|x|^{n-2}} 
& = \int_0^\varepsilon r^{n-1} \int_{S(0,1)} \frac{dy}{|ry|^{n-2}} \, dr \\
& = |S(0,1)| \int_0^\varepsilon r \, dr \\
& = \frac 12 |S(0,1)| \varepsilon^2.
\end{align*}